# Apply describe with filter on column specific in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive `hive_tbl` with columns `'col_1','col_2','col_3'`. I have created a dataframe on top of above data.

Now i am getting statistics of the columns specified using `describe()` i am getting the result as below.

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|summary|          col1    |          col2    |   col3           |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  count|          17547479|          17547479|          17547479|
|   mean|2.0946498354549963| 1.474746257282603|1943.9881619448768|
| stddev|1.7921560893864912|1.2898177241581452| 40126.73218327477|
|    min|               0.0|               0.0|               0.0|
|    max|              99.0|              60.0|       1.6240624E8|
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

The above count is giving the count of the records in the entire table.
But can we apply filter specific to columns when using describe i.e. i have some blanks/values to be ignored when getting the count for some column eg `col_1` has record count with good values `549023`.

Can we get below result.

```
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|summary|          col1    |          col2    |   col3           |
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  count|          549023  |            854049|          17547479|
|   mean|2.0946498354549963| 1.474746257282603|1943.9881619448768|
| stddev|1.7921560893864912|1.2898177241581452| 40126.73218327477|
|    min|               0.0|               0.0|               0.0|
|    max|              99.0|              60.0|       1.6240624E8|
+-------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: What is the condition to ignore values in the summary statistics? As far as I know, Null values are not taken into account by `describe()`. So it seems your `DataFrame` does not contain Nulls?

Comment: Filter like `col_1='NAME'` and get the statistics for that column likewise when using `describe()`

Comment: You can do `df.filter(df['col1'].isNotNull()).describe()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.na().drop()` in order to discard any rows containing `NaN` or `NULL` values in particular columns. For example,

```
df.na.drop(subset=["col1"])
```

will drop all the rows where `col1` is `NaN` or `NULL`. Finally, you can now `describe()` your filtered dataframe:

```
filtered_df = df.na.drop(subset=["col1"])
filtered_df.describe()
```